# Confusing about when to (not to) use backslash '\' for escaping

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line, grep

I am very confused about when I should use '\'.

Consider the examples:

(1)

```
$ grep -Eh '^(bz|gz|zip)' filenames.txt
```

it matches for result that start with either bz , gz, or zip.

(2)

```
$ echo "(555) 123-4567" | grep -E '^\(?[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)? [0-9] [0-9][0-9]$'
```

output: (555) 123-4567

---

1. With example (1) , why doesn't it require '\' for escaping parentheses ()
2. With example (2) , why does it require '\' for escaping ()?

I am using Ubuntu distro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parentheses in each of your examples mean different things.

In the first example, the parentheses are *grouping* and are *not* matched against the filenames. So you find files that start with `bz` and not `(bz`.

In your second example, the parentheses are *literal* and actually appear in the phone number you're matching against.

Comment: Note that grep's `-E` option actually changes which things need to be escaped -- without it, `( ... )` matches literal parens and `\( ... \)` is a group, but with `-E` the meanings are reversed.